# React-native Image not appearing

Tags: android, react-native

I am using React-Native v0.60.4, running on android simulator, generates an image by using `react-native-signature-capture`, the image can be opened manually and show correctly. I want to display this image by using `Image`, but it displays nothing.

I checked but there is no error/warning message.

```
<Image
     style={{width: 200, height: 200}}
     source={{uri: '/storage/emulated/0/saved_signature/signature.png'}}
/>
```

This should be very basic usage of `Image` but why nothing displayed?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `imagepicker` to bring the `image` in the path, use the `image module`, and look at the `image`.

Example

```js
import ImagePicker from 'react-native-image-picker';
...
  ImagePicker.showImagePicker(options, response => {
        let source = response;
        this.setState({
          filePath: source,
        });

...
<Image 
          source={{ uri: this.state.filePath.uri}} 
          style={{width: 100, height: 100}} />
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to show a local image than you have to use require property instead of uri like this:-

image from local storage:-

```
<Image 
style={{width: 200, height: 200}}
source={require('/storage/emulated/0/saved_signature/signature.png')} />
```

For dynamic image or image from uri:-

```
<Image 
style={{width: 200, height: 200}}
source={{uri: 'https://facebook.github.io/react/logo-og.png'}} />
```

Answer (score 0):

To display an image, you need to require it before

```
import myImage from './path_to_image.png'

<Image source={myImage} style={{ width: 200, height: 200 }} />
```

For more information, you have [this documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/image.html)

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass in a `require()` to `source` prop like so:

```
const ImageDetail = props => {
  return (
    <View>
      <Image source={require('/storage/emulated/0/saved_signature/signature.png')} />
      <Text>{props.title}</Text>
    </View>
  );
};
```

Make sure your path is correct as well in that it's not `../storage` or `../../storage`.

And all this would be in your child component for example, keeping in mind that you did not specify which component you are on. Once you have ensured the image renders then you want to go to your parent component and pass it the prop of whatever name you choose, for example `imageSource`.

Then you pass in that require again and the relative path:

```
const ImageScreen = () => {
  return (
    <View>
      <ImageDetail
        title='Signature One'
        imageSource={require("/storage/emulated/0/saved_signature/signature1.png")}
      />
      <ImageDetail
        title='Signature Two'
        imageSource={require("/storage/emulated/0/saved_signature/signature2.png")}
      />
      <ImageDetail
        title='Signature Three'
        imageSource={require("/storage/emulated/0/saved_signature/signature3.png")}
      />
    </View>
  );
};
```

I would then console log props on that child component and if your setup is similar to whats above you should see:

```
{title: "Signature One", imageSource: 3}
{title: "Signature Two", imageSource: 4}
{title: "Signature Three", imageSource: 5}
```

The 3, 4, 5 would be an identifier so don't worry about that, but I put it there just in case you see it.

Now in your child component you can remove that `require('/storage/emulated/0/saved_signature/signature.png')` from your `source={}` prop and replace it with `<Image source={props.imageSource} />` or whatever you called it.

Comment: Thanks, `require` does not work for my issue, it complains with error I fixed it by  appending `file://` to image path

Answer (score 0):

You can grab the image as base64-string directly out of the component and delegate it to Image:

```
const [ image, setImage ] = useState( '' )

return <>
  <SignatureCapture onSaveEvent={({ encoded, pathName }) => setImage( encoded ) }/>

  {image && <Image source={{ uri:image }}/>}
<>
```